# How to use Images in the concrete syntax definition of a language

Tags: lightning-workbench, f-alloy

In the LightningVLM module, there is an IMAGE concept with an url property.

I tried in my F-Alloy specification to write the following:

```
guard_mapImage(n:Node,i:IMAGE){
     i.url="/path/to/myImage.png"
}
```

but images are not displayed (I get red crosses instead).

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "url" property of the "IMAGE" concept needs to be set to a valid URL.

You could use "file:///path/to/image.png" to refer to an image on your computer.

In addition, it's also possible to use [Eclipse Platform URLs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fplatform-scheme-uri.html) to refer to files inside your Eclipse workspace, eg. "platform:/resource/MyLightningProject/MyLanguage/image.png".